# Saving space when writing floats (radian angles) to a file

Tags: c, binary, angle

I want to write some radian angles to a binary file. Is there any way I can save space while doing so?

I considered converting them to degrees and writing them out as a short but when converting to a short they loose their fractional part so that wasn't going to work...

Any ideas?

EDIT: I only need 2 or 3 decimal points precision

Comment: If you write the binary representation, a `float` almost certainly requires four bytes. Is that compact enough? String representations take more if you want some precision retained.

Comment: How much resolution/precision do you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method from the Quake source code that writes them out as a byte like this:

```
((int)radian*256/360) & 255 //radian is the angle
```

Then reads it in like this:

```
b * (360.0f/256) //b is the byte read in
```

Which I tested and it leaves about 2 decimal places of precision, which should be okay for me.

Answer (score 1):

How much precision / resolution do you need?

If you can do with a precision / resolution of half a circle, 1 bit per value should be enough: that is, you can fit 8 values in a byte.

...

Comment: That's insane... Would you like to get your salary in 1000$ resolution? You either get $1000 or nothing...

Comment: @H2CO3 You missed the point. The answer to the OP's question depends entirely on his precision needs which he failed to specify. This answer points up the possible cost of such an oversight.

Comment: Yes but this is too extreme anyway. I think it's obvious that he wants some more precision...

Answer (score 1):

You have two things to worry about: range and precision.  And you haven't given us enough information about either one.

So I'll make some reasonable (I hope) assumptions.

I'll assume that all the values are in the range 0 to 2π (0 to 360°).

If you store such values as 32-bit `float`, you're using 1 bit for the sign (for numbers that are always non-negative), 8 bits for the exponent (which will never be very big), and 23 bits for the significand (which is likely more precision than you need).  If you use a 64-bit `double`, you're obviously using even more space.

The most obvious solution is to use a small unsigned type (since you don't need negative values), using a fixed-point representation so that a value of `1` represents some fraction of a radian.  For values from 0 to 2π (0 to about 6.28), you need 3 bits before the <strike>decimal</strike> binary point.  Now you just need to decided how many bits of fraction you want.

If you use an 8-bit unsigned type (typically `unsigned char`), that gives you 5 bits after the binary point, so a value of 1 represents 2<sup>-5</sup> radians, which is about 1.82°.  This is *barely* enough to give you the "2 or 3 decimal points precision" you say you need, but I suspect it's more coarse than you actually want.

If you use a 16-bit unsigned type (typically `unsigned short`), that gives you 13 bits after the binary point, so a value of 1 represents 2<sup>-13</sup> radian; that's about 0.007°, or about 25 arcseconds.  This may well be enough precision for your purposes, and it's typically half the storage of `float`.

All this assumes that just storing the values as 32-bit `float`s isn't good enough.  Disk space (if that's your concern) is cheap these days, and getting cheaper.

Note also that storing binary values in files can be problematic if you want to share the data among different systems.  Byte ordering in particular can be an issue.  If you can define a format that's a stream of bytes (say, pairs of bytes representing 16-bit unsigned values, with the most significant byte first -- that's "network byte order"), you can alleviate that problem.  Integer values are easier to deal with than floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

used a fixed point representation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

Compression?

Can be a bit costly to implement but it may take even less space than tightly packed binary data. Plus, the uncompressed form can be pretty much anything, such as human-readable ASCII.